# how to insert data-ajax value in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried to make data-toggle="tab" keep showing after refresh, the problem is the data I tried to show is triggered by data-ajax, so I tried this code it work, but still didnt trigger data-ajax to showing the data..

here's my slice page

```
<ul class="text-center alert col-md-12" id="myTab">
   <a class="btn btn-primary changeTable" data-ajax="tableresponses.php" href="#table_asall" data-toggle="tab">All Assets List</a>
   <a class="btn btn-primary changeTable" data-ajax="tableresponses1.php" href="#table_asborrow" data-toggle="tab">Used Assets</a>
   <a class="btn btn-primary changeTable" data-ajax="tableresponses2.php" href="#table_asbroken" data-toggle="tab">Damaged Assets</a>
</ul>
```

and here's my js

```
$(function() {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
        console.log("ok0");
        window.localStorage.setItem('activeTab1', $(e.target).attr('data-ajax'));
        console.log("ok1");
    });
    var activeTab  = window.localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
        console.log("ok2");
    var activeTab1 = window.localStorage.getItem('activeTab1');
        console.log("ok3");
    if (activeTab) {
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"], [data-ajax="' + activeTab1 + '"]').tab('show');
        window.localStorage.removeItem("activeTab");
        console.log("ok4");
    }
});
```

Comment: Get the stored PHP URL and re-do the ajax request.

Comment: What is purpose of comma within selector passed to `jQuery()` call?

Comment: @guest271314 for separating the call function ?

Comment: Are you trying to select one element, two elements, or the same element twice at `$('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"], [data-ajax="' + activeTab1 + '"]')`?

Comment: what im trying is call a href value and data-ajax value after refreshed